# curl and wget behavior differently when querying Docker Hub rate

Tags: curl, wget, dockerhub

I am wondering what makes the curl and wget behavior differently when query docker hub download rate.

[Dockre docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/download-rate-limit/) said we can use the following curl command to get the docker hub remain rate.

```
docker_hub_rate() {
  local IMAGE=${1:-ratelimitpreview/test}
  local RESPONSE=$(wget -qO- "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${IMAGE}:pull")
  local TOKEN=$(echo ${RESPONSE} | sed 's/.*"token":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/')
  local HEADER="Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}"
  local URL="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${IMAGE}/manifests/latest"
  RESPONSE=$(curl --head -H "${HEADER}" "${URL}" 2>&1)
  echo ${RESPONSE}
}
```

I have an environment where there is no curl, only wget is available. So I change the command to

```
docker_hub_rate() {
  local IMAGE=${1:-ratelimitpreview/test}
  local RESPONSE=$(wget -qO- "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${IMAGE}:pull")
  local TOKEN=$(echo ${RESPONSE} | sed 's/.*"token":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/')
  local HEADER="Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}"
  local URL="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${IMAGE}/manifests/latest"
  RESPONSE=$(wget -qS --header="${HEADER}" -O /dev/null "${URL}" 2>&1)
  echo ${RESPONSE}
}
```

I am still able to get the rate.

However I found that wget command consumed one docker hub rate, while curl did not consume any docker hub rate.

I am wondering what makes the curl and wget behavior differently?

Thanks,

both curl and wget consume no docker hub download rate.

Comment: Perhaps you should familiarise yourself with what the [--head](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-I) option does

Answer (score 1):

`curl --head` and `wget -S` are different

curl

> -I, --head
>
> (HTTP FTP FILE) Fetch the headers only! HTTP-servers feature the command HEAD which this uses to get nothing but the header of a document. When used on an FTP or FILE file, curl displays the file size and last modification time only.

wget:

> -S will show headers, but it executes a GET, not a HEAD. In other words, it will fetch the entire URL.

> With Wget, adding --spider implies that you want to send a HEAD request (as opposed to GET or POST).

[source](https://superuser.com/questions/197009/wget-head-request)